# Patching a csv file generates error

Tags: linux, diff

I have two CSV files namely `test1.csv` and `test2.csv` separated by a custom delimiter Pipe Sign(`|`). I am getting their changes through the `diff` command as follows

```
diff test2.csv test1.csv > test.patch
```

Now what I am doing to get the patch is to create a third file `test.csv` and run the patch as follows

```
patch test.csv < test.patch
```

But when I run this patch command I get the following errors.

```
patching file test.csv
Hunk #1 FAILED at 1.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file test.csv.rej
```

Can you please tell me whats wrong in this method?

- EDIT:
  I have two files with name test1.csv and test2.csv.
  Commands are executed in the following manner

> diff test2.csv test1.csv > test.patch
>
> (after patch creation i create a
> new file 'test.csv')
>
> patch test.csv < test.patch

Comment: Are you sure it's the same file? One is called `test.csv` but the others are called `testN.csv`. Are you sure you generated the patch the right way around? (Try swapping the order of the arguments to diff, or calling `patch -R` to reverse the patch when applying it). Other than that looks sane, but there's not enough detail here to reproduce or see your problem ourselves.

Comment: The patch is to create a third File. I am not applying it on the testN.csv file, i need the difference of the two files to be stored in a third file so i get the patch file and then create a new file(manually) and then i am patching the code to the newly created file to get the diff output

Comment: @HardCode, update your question with commands executed in sequence.

Comment: `patch` does not work reliably for very regular files (it is hard to find point of reference if the whole file looks almost the same). Try different modi of the `diff` (-u for "unified", for instance, with a big context). It might work better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ex. `test.csv` should resemble `test2.csv`. Look at the below ex.

```
 $ cat f1.csv
a
b
c
z
 $ cat f3.csv
a
b
c
d
 $ diff f1.csv f3.csv  > diffop
 $ cp f1.csv tst
 $ cat tst
a
b
c
z
 $ patch tst diffop
patching file tst
 $ cat tst
a
b
c
d
```

Comment: looking at contents of f1.csv and f3.csv i would only like to have "z" entry in the resultant file.

Comment: by resultant file you mean `tst`, always use names so that its easy for people to understand.

Comment: Yes i mean the End file and in this case "tst" and can we change it to ".csv" extention so that it matches its parent(>  f1.csv) structure